# Return and call multiple value from function

Tags: matlab, for-loop, return, return-value, function-call

I am trying to return all values of for loop from my function and also I need to call them outside of the function.But i only get last row of the for loop, I also need previous result of for loop.
Here is my code

```
i=input('Enter a start row: ');
j=input('Enter a end row: ');
c=input('Enter classifier variable column number:')


search= importfiledataset('search-queries-features.csv',i,j);

[n,p]=size(search);

 if j>n
        disp('Please enter a smaller number!');
 end
  [D1,Eps1]=findD(i,j,c,search);
   disp(D1);
   disp(n1);

function [D1,Eps1] = findD(i,j,c,search)      %Find D vlaues with for loop for each classification value 

    for numOfClassifier = 1 : 100
        a = search(search(:,c)==numOfClassifier,:) ; 
        q1 = a(all(~isnan(a),2),:); % for nan - rows
        D1 = a(:,all(~isnan(a)))  % for nan - columns WE FIND D1

        n1=size(D1,1) %number of record belongs to classification

        sampleSpace = size(search,1) %sample space of the priop probability(#of c1 + #of c2 .... cn)

        pc1 = n1/sampleSpace %prior probability of the n

        mu1 = mean(D1) %mean of D1

        Z1 = D1 - mu1 % centered data of D1

        Eps1 = (1/n1)*(transpose(Z1)*Z1) %covariance matrix if Z1


        numOfClassifier = numOfClassifier + 1;
        if search(:,c) ~= numOfClassifier
            break
        end 
    end  
end
```

I need to return

- D1
- Eps1

I want to return the entire values of for loop but I only end up with values from the last row.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the iteration results in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), and return the cell array:

Function returning two cell arrays (I named them `allD1` and `allEps1`):

```
function [allD1, allEps1] = findD(i,j,c,search)
```

Initialize the cell arrays to empty cells before the loop:

```
allD1 = {};
allEps1 = {};
```

Add `D1` and `Eps1` to the end of the cell arrays (place it before the line with the `break` statement):

```
allD1{end + 1} = D1;
allEps1{end + 1} = Eps1;
```

---

Here is the modified code:

```
i=input('Enter a start row: ');
j=input('Enter a end row: ');
c=input('Enter classifier variable column number:')


search= importfiledataset('search-queries-features.csv',i,j);

[n,p]=size(search);

 if j>n
        disp('Please enter a smaller number!');
 end
  [D1,Eps1]=findD(i,j,c,search);
   disp(D1);
   disp(n1);

function [allD1, allEps1] = findD(i,j,c,search)      %Find D vlaues with for loop for each classification value 
    %Initialize empty cell arrays
    allD1 = {};
    allEps1 = {};

    for numOfClassifier = 1 : 100
        a = search(search(:,c)==numOfClassifier,:) ; 
        q1 = a(all(~isnan(a),2),:); % for nan - rows
        D1 = a(:,all(~isnan(a)))  % for nan - columns WE FIND D1

        n1=size(D1,1) %number of record belongs to classification

        sampleSpace = size(search,1) %sample space of the priop probability(#of c1 + #of c2 .... cn)

        pc1 = n1/sampleSpace %prior probability of the n

        mu1 = mean(D1) %mean of D1

        Z1 = D1 - mu1 % centered data of D1

        Eps1 = (1/n1)*(transpose(Z1)*Z1) %covariance matrix if Z1

        %Add D1 (and Eps1) to the end of the cell array
        allD1{end + 1} = D1;
        allEps1{end + 1} = Eps1;

        numOfClassifier = numOfClassifier + 1;
        if search(:,c) ~= numOfClassifier
            break
        end 
    end  
end
```

---

Cell arrays are more general then arrays - cells can store values of different types and shapes, opposed to arrays where all elements must be of the same type.

In your case, multi-dimensional arrays might fit, but it's more confusing.

With cell arrays, each cell holds the result of the matching iteration.
For example: `allD1{3}` holds the value of `D1` in the third iteration.